# Profile the go build process

Tags: go, compilation, cpu-usage, profiler

Is there a way to profile the go build process? We notice that our build process is taking up a lot of cpu and memory.  While it could be that our code indeed needs the amount of resources, we want to profile the build process and see where all the usage is going.
Thanks

We tried adding more logs with -x options and tried to correlate the output with resource usage but it produced inconsistent results as in our system.  The -gcflags with -m and memprofilerate  etc seem to be only for the resulting process and not for the build process itself.

Answer (score 0):

From this blog post, which is worth reading in full: https://blog.howardjohn.info/posts/go-build-times/#scaling-cpu

`go build -ldflags='-cpuprofile /tmp/linker-cpu.prof' -gcflags='-cpuprofile /tmp/compiler-cpu.prof' .`